# How to retrive multiple documents in Couchbase with python client

Tags: couchbase

Currently, the Couchbase Python client doesn't implement getMulti() method yet. How can I retrive multiple document in bulk by providing multiple keys?

I am asking question  about [couchbase](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/couchbase/couchbaseclient.py) not memcached client

Comment: Are you sure about that? I can find this method in source code https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/couchbase/memcachedclient.py#L332

Comment: Sorry, I was asking question about couchbase client. Your code is for memcached client memcachedclient.py. Getmulti() not in couchbaseclient.py: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-python-client/blob/master/couchbase/couchbaseclient.py

Answer (score 1):

As you notice today it is not supported by the Couchbase client. So you have to put this in a loop and do individual gets.

An issue has been logged on the subject:
http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/PYCBC-49